# Retrieving cells during OnRowDataBound call results in out of bounds exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get data from the rows that are generated in a GridView. Here is my table:

[image]

```
protected void viewStoryTime_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
}
```

The output is:

Hours
6.25
3
5
4

I however need the data from the date column. But when I do:

```
protected void viewStoryTime_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the date using cell index is very fragile. It only throws exception at run time.

You can easily achieve the same result by casting [DataItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx) to appropiate object.

[image]

```
public class  Data
{
    public decimal Hours { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = new List<Data>
        {
            new Data { Hours = 6.25m, Notes = "One", Date = DateTime.Parse("07/11/2013")},
            new Data { Hours = 3m, Notes = "Two", Date = DateTime.Parse("07/11/2013")},
            new Data { Hours = 5m, Notes = "Three", Date = DateTime.Parse("07/11/2013")},
            new Data { Hours = 4m, Notes = "Four", Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900")}
        };
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {         
        var data = e.Row.DataItem as Data; 
        var date = data.Date;

        // Cast to DataRowView if your datasource is DataTable or DataSet
        // var rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: The table is being pulled from a SQL server database. I created an instance of the data Data and did the following:         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var data = e.Row.DataItem as Data;
            var date = data.Date;
       
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data);
        } and got no output

Comment: Please look at this answers regarding how to cast to DataItem to DataRowView - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16737479/296861